# Azure FileShare log configuration

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, fileshare

I would like to log access on my FileShare (connect, read, write, delete).
Where can I configure logging and how can I access log?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storage doesn't support logging for Azure File yet. It's planned to offer it in Azure Monitor shortly." For now metrics are available which can be enabled using this article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-monitor-storage-account

Comment: Aa, oukeeej. Not good information, so we have to wait till H2 2017